# How do I implement thread pool for the single task need to be handled by multiple threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

Run method in the separate class called ExportShipmentThread which implements Runnable :

```
public void run() {

    for (Shipment s : shipmentList) {
        System.out.println("hi " + s.getId() + " Thread name "  + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Main in separate class:

```
    int numberOfThreads = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());

    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads);
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){  
        ExportShipmentThread command = new ExportShipmentThread(shipmentList);
        executorService.execute(command);
    }

    executorService.shutdown();
```

Result:

Copied first few records,

```
hi 2390900 Thread name pool-1-thread-1
hi 2390900 Thread name pool-1-thread-3
hi 2390900 Thread name pool-1-thread-2
hi 2390900 Thread name pool-1-thread-4
hi 2391990 Thread name pool-1-thread-1
hi 2391990 Thread name pool-1-thread-4
hi 2391990 Thread name pool-1-thread-2
hi 2391990 Thread name pool-1-thread-3
```

Here same data is getting processed again like `2390900` is repeated by different threads, I want the output to be without duplicates but processed by different threads in the pool. Please advice.

Comment: isnt that is what's expected? you are asking the threads to sleep for 5 secs, the next thread begins execution and picks up the first element from shipmentlist.

Comment: If all you want is for the listed name of the thread to be the same, you can use a thread factory which sets the same name to all the threads created.

Answer (score 0):

Your thread should only work on a Shipment and not all of them. Then for each shipment in the list, run a thread with the shipment.